# PHP NSUpdate Update of an TXT String

Tags: php, dns, bind, named

iam using NSUpdate to update DNS Records from PHP

all things working, but somthing going wrong when i want ***update/Add*** TXT Record

adding an Text Record is not so hard like ***SRV*** OF ***SPF***

nope :) rlly

***The Problem:***
trying to add somthing like "This IS an TXT record"

after sending it from PHP to NSUPDATE (works with other Records)

Bind DNS Server get this :
***Domain IN TXT "This" "IS" "an" "TXT" "Record"***
but this is wrong ! inspected my code, looked arround..it dosent work ..

**code :**

```
    <?php
        if ($txt_true) {
             $ttl2 = '36';
                // TXT string could be almost anything, just make sure it's quoted.
                // $txt_var = str_replace("'", "", $txt_var);
                // $txt_var = str_replace('"', "", $txt_var);
                //$txt_var = '"'. $txt_var.'"';
                $data .= "update add ".$sub.".".$domain.". ".$ttl2." IN TXT ".$txt_var."\n"; 

          }
```

this going to NSupdate ( data + nsupdate etc...) dotn follow block that is out commented

**here:**

```
function dns_update ($id_domain,$mydata) {
 global $nsupdate;

 if (domain_exists($id_domain)) {
  $infos = domain_infos($id_domain);
  $domain = $infos['domain'];
  $dnsip = $infos['dnsip'];
  $key = $infos['key'];
  if ($key != '') { $add = ' -y '.$key; }
  $data = "server $dnsip\n";
  $data .= "zone $domain\n";
  $data .= $mydata;
  $data .= "\n";
  $result = `echo "$data" | $nsupdate$add`;
  return $result;

 } else {
  return false;
 }
}
```

**and Quote TXT Record** happens from

HTML => INPUT => DO => Wirte DB & Function => NSUPDATE

Comment: Need to add : in SQL DB the strin is writen correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need quotes around the text data. If it contains any embedded quotes, they need to be escaped:

```
$txt_var = str_replace('"', '\"', $txt_var);
$data .= "update add $sub.$domain. $ttl2 IN TXT \"$txt_var\"\n";
```

Since this string contains double quotes, you should use single quotes in your `echo` statement:

```
$result = `echo '$data' | $nsupdate$add`;
```

However, a much better idea would be to use an API rather than doing this through the command line. See the [Net_DNS2](https://netdns2.com/2015/03/dns-in-php-how-to-use-the-net_dns2-library/) library.

Comment: thx, that is it ;D lol sorry cant vote your up because my Reputation ;/